# How to get service lifetime by service type?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

How can i get the service lifetime type(Singleton/Scoped/Transient) by service type using `ServiceProvider` or any other Extension class dot net core provides for dependency injection?

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? Can you provide more context for your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out what is the configured lifetime of some particular service, at the end of [`Startup.ConfigureServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-configureservices-method) you can look through `IServiceCollection` for whatever entries you are interested in, and check their [`ServiceDescriptor.Lifetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#properties). For example:

```
ServiceDescriptor[] descriptors =
    services.Where(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)).ToArray();
```

The configuration should not change after that point, so there should be no need to hack into `IServiceProvider`.

Comment: I was able to reach the same service lifetime info via VS2022 during a debug session. With a breakpoint set after var app = builder.Build() in an ASP.Net application a Quickwatch window allowed navigation to a list of configured services.